# How this for loop makes a 8x8 board?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```
var size = 8;

var board = "";

for (var y = 0; y < size; y++) {
  for (var x = 0; x < size; x++) {
    if ((x + y) % 2 == 0)
      board += " ";
    else
      board += "#";
  }
  board += "\n";
}

console.log(board);
```

Now I understand that this creates a 8x8 board. I have problem in understanding how and what does 2nd "for" loop do (I want to understand its behavior). 
As far as I understand, these 2 loops create a 2D coordinate system with 1st for loop covering y-axis and 2nd covering x-axis. I understand how the following block works.

```
{
 if ((x + y) % 2 == 0)
    board += " ";
 else
    board += "#";
}
```

I don't understand how the second for loop covers x-axis. 
I started reading eloquent javascript and this question was given as an exercise. It gave a short info about nested loops but not to this complexity.
I searched previous answers but didn't get information about this. Any help?

Comment: You are correct. It might help to see the y and x at each step. Add a print statement in the loop for (x,y) and you'll see how the board is covered.

Comment: I recommend to set a breakpoint before the loop and then step through the code. Nothing is better to understand the flow than actually stepping through it. Learn how to set breakpoints here: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Watching" the variables change may give you a better feeling for how the program works:

```js
var prog= [],
    table= document.querySelector('table'),
    sx= document.getElementById('x'),
    sy= document.getElementById('y'),
    smod= document.getElementById('mod');

function display(x, y, c) {
  prog.push([x,y,c]);
}

function runProgram() {
  var p= prog.shift();
  if(p) {
    var x= p[0], y= p[1], c= p[2], mod= (x+y) % 2;
    sx.innerHTML= x;
    sy.innerHTML= y;
    smod.innerHTML= mod;
    table.rows[y].cells[x].innerHTML= c;
    setTimeout(runProgram, 200);
  }
}

var size = 8;

var board = "";

for (var y = 0; y < size; y++) {
  for (var x = 0; x < size; x++) {
    if ((x + y) % 2 == 0) {
      board += " ";
      display(x, y, ' ');
    }
    else {
      board += "#";
      display(x, y, '#');
    }
  }
  board += "\n";
}
console.log(board);

runProgram();
```

```css
th {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
y= <span id="y"></span><br>
x= <span id="x"></span><br>
(x+y) % 2 = <span id="mod"></span>
<table>
  <tr><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th></tr>
  <tr><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th></tr>
  <tr><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th></tr>
  <tr><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th></tr>
  <tr><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th></tr>
  <tr><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th></tr>
  <tr><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th></tr>
  <tr><th><th><th><th><th><th><th><th></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this truth table, which shows the even/odd result of adding two integers:

```
|  X is even  |  Y is even  | X + Y is even | Write a space?
|     F       |      F      |      T        |      T 
|     T       |      F      |      F        |      F
|     F       |      T      |      F        |      F
|     T       |      T      |      T        |      T
```

So starting at position (0, 0), the inner loop would write a space. Consider then next row, (0, 1) - the inner loop would write a number sign, because the result of `1 + 0` is odd. The pattern continues for the entire board, regardless of the current row or column.

Consequently you can also tell whether any square on an arbitrary board would be empty or have a number sign.

Comment: I'm confused. The next "row" should be (0,1), correct? Does the code run as (0,0),(0,1),(0,2)...(0,7) or (0,0),(1,0),(2,0)...(7,0)? I am guessing it is the former since code runs 1st for loop first and then 2nd for loop so it should be (0,0),(0,1),(0,2)...(0,7) then (1,0),(1,1),(1,2)...(1,7) and so on.

Comment: You are correct, the "next row" would start on (0,1), so it follows the latter case. You can see the result if you change the inner loop body to `board += " (" + x + "," + y + ") ";`

Answer (score 1):

Basic programming knowledge tells us that a for loop is simply a means of adjusting the value of a variable a certain number of times. In your case, you are basically "counting" starting at zero and incrementing `y` until it is greater than size.

So the second, ["nested" for loop](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/programming/looping/p/nested-for-loops) basically takes this very simple concept and expands on it. So for every `y`th iteration of the outer loop `x` will start at `0` and go to `size-1`.

Consider this modified code sample:

```
for (var y = 0; y < size; y++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        board += " " + (size * y + x);
    }
    board += "\n";
}
```

Produces this output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47
48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55
56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63
```

In this way, the variables `x` and `y` seem to be appropriately named. For every row `y`, `x` will have gone from `0` to `size-1`.

Hope this makes sense!

Comment: Yes it makes sense. Although what do you mean by (size * y + x) ? Is it (size * y)+x or size*(y+x)? Program will run (size * y)+x I think you meant the latter. :)

Comment: @MarineBiologist You should read up on operator precedence - these are the rules that determine what order an expression is evaluated in. In this case, Javascript uses the same rules as algebra, so multiplication happens before addition.